# Есть ли в природе некий генератор секретных переменных для Docker или просто для неких проектов?

Tags: docker, непрерывная-интеграция

Из заголовка наверняка не слишком понятно, что я имею ввиду, поэтому объясню.

**Ситуация:**

Есть некое количество сервисов, крутящихся на продакшене в `Docker`, каждый отдельно. Им нужны некие переменные окружения, на основании которых в них будет происходить некая криптография. Пускай это будет 1 переменная, назовем ее `APP_SECRET`. Ее можно генерировать двумя способами: вручную, периодически обновляя некий условный `.env` файл (или записывая ее еще куда-то, откуда потом ее сможет найти код) в каждом проекте, и автоматически, тоже в каждом проекте.

Переменная должна быть постоянной, известной в рамках только одного проекта (то есть это не некий `shared secret`), и повторяемой для одной и той же `CI/CD` сборки проекта. Ну то есть завязанной на дате обновления некоего `lock-файла` внутри проекта, к примеру.

Вручную - понятны минусы. Явно реже будет генериться, непонятно каким образом, непонятно куда и когда и как может утечь.

Автоматически - тут понятны плюсы. Генерация может быть завязана на каждую сборку в `CI/CD`. Алгоритм будет известен, и если его верно подобрать, то генерируемые им значения - безопасны.

**Вопрос:**

Есть ли некие инструменты, как для `Docker`, так и просто для неких проектов (но только на `PHP`, если это критично), которые способны при каждой сборке проекта (по сути, это может быть просто некий `sh-скрипт`, запускающий что угодно) генерировать описанную выше переменную, и после записывать ее в `.env`, к примеру?

**PS:** понятно, что написать такое можно и самому, десятком разных способов, но если есть уже готовые инструменты, то я бы предпочел как минимум сначала изучить их.

Comment: вам надо изобрести хэш-сумму от номера сборки?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нет, мне нужно изобрести полноценный инструмент, умеющий и некий хеш генерировать при сборке, и потом класть его в .env ну или сразу устанавливать в окружении как значение некоей переменной, и тд.

Comment: установка значения переменной окружения: `имя=значение`. чтобы это имя с привязанным значением унаследовали дочерние процессы, имя надо [экспортировать](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export): `export имя=значение`. в качестве значения можно использовать результат выполнения какой-нибудь программы: `имя=$(программа её-аргументы)`. программ, вычисляющих хэш-суммы — вполне достаточно: начиная с [самых примитивных](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cksum.html).